# Relative links in Swift Markdown

Tags: xcode, swift, documentation, markdown

Is it possible to link to files or images in the same project using [Swift documentation markup](http://nshipster.com/swift-documentation/) kind of like [Github does](https://github.com/blog/1395-relative-links-in-markup-files)? I have [snapshots](https://github.com/facebook/ios-snapshot-test-case) of all my view classes and would really like to include those images in the documentation.

Something like this:

```
![Snapshot](ReferenceImages_64/RealmUITests.RealmIconsSnapshotTests/testLikeIcon@2x)
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for symbol documentation and Playgrounds, but there's a difference.

For symbol documentation, only links to online images are supported.

Online *and* local images are supported in Playgrounds.

Local images have to be in the Playground's `Resources` folder.

```
/*:

 ![Remote image: docs + Playground](http://example.fake/image.png)

 ![Local image: only Playground](image.png)

*/
```

*[Reference: Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/Images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH17-SW1)*

*Note: doesn't work with 7.3 beta.*